# Bootargs to Mount Rootfs on SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK board using TFTP & QSPI

Tags: embedded, bitbucket, embedded-linux, yocto, atmel

I was not able to mount rootfs using sdcard so i am trying to mount it using tftp and QSPI.
I have loaded my rootfs.jffs2 file at  RAM address (0x21000000) using tftp protocol.i just want bootargs to pass which will mount my rootfs on board.

I just need help that how can i mount rootfs.using sd-card my u-boot and kernel are working so i dont want to change it at this time because it is working fine just i have problem with rootfs.'

Just suggest me bootargs to mount rootfs

Answer (score 0):

There should be something like "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" in your bootargs. It stands for MMC block device 0, partition 2. If you still fail to mount rootfs on SD card, please provide the full boot log.

Comment: VFS: Cannot open root device "mmcblk0p2" or unknown-block(179,2): error -30                         
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:                     
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2) ]---      
random: fast init done

Comment: printenv        
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait atmel.pm_modes=standby,ulp1
bootcmd=fatload mmc 0:1 0x24000000 sama5d27_som1_ek.itb; bootm 0x24000000#kernel_dtb
bootdelay=1
ethact=gmac0
ethaddr=54:10:ec:a9:81:79
fdtcontroladdr=27b68460
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial

Environment size: 308/16380 bytes

Comment: please check my env and other arguments

Comment: what was shown after "here are the available partitions:" ?  how many mmc devices you have? and Are you laying rootfs on partition 2?

Comment: only one device and i am using partitions 2

Comment: SD card should be loaded before it would be mounted. In your boot log, there should be similar messages as : [  286.140413] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0007
[  286.150926] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SDCIT 7.29 GiB
[  286.170497]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[  287.691840] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null) . If not, MMC may not be enabled. Please check your kernel config if  CONFIG_MMC, CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK were enabled?

Comment: can i change CONFIG_MMC using u-boot,i am using official image to flash ie(https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage#Create_a_SD_card_with_the_demo) it should work withoud any changes but not working in my case

Comment: No, you can't. You may need some one else who have experience using SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK to support.

Comment: " EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode." i cannot see all other operations are shown